# Central data storage for apps in Software Center

Tags: software-center, application-development

I am trying to make a package for the Software Center, but so far the problem is that there seems to be no central place to store data for all users.

We need that to store license files that the application can later add if the users want to use the non-free parts of our software. Also we use this for storing document templates that some users edit and make them available for all users on the system.

Is there any solution for this kind of problems? From what I see on this page:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/

> Write all configuration settings to ~/.<pkgName>
>   (This can be one file or a directory containing multiple configuration files.)

EDIT: While talking to the Ubuntu staff it turns out there is no way you can have a central file storage for all users. At least not at the moment. I tried adding scripts to the debian source package that would create folders, but the staff looked at them and did not approve the version. At the moment we are saving the common files in the user .config folder.

Answer (score 3):

For licenses, you will want to use the license key mechanism built into Oneiric and the http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com application submission portal.

I think you answered your own question as you want to store user space configuration settings to ~/.<somedir> or ~/.config/<somedir> - following the XDG standards would be suggested.

Comment: That's correct. To learn more about licences, check out http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/licence-key-infrastructure/

Comment: I think this would be a valid approach if the app was sold from the  Software Center. As far as I understand the this license storage mechanism that Ubuntu provides is utilized by it and the license is automatically installed.

Our idea is a little different. As I wrote above the license can be added later and it is not sold by the Software Center. It is more of an upsell which is allowed by Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

You could provide a full debian package instead of a zip for installation under /opt/.

During your .deb installation, you can create a folder `/usr/lib/<appname>/templates` and make it world writable, like putting a `chmod o+w /usr/lib/<appname>/templates` in your `<appname>.postinst` script.

Comment: As far as I understand I should be able to provide a source package which should be used to build a .deb. Also the package will be audited before approval and this behavior will be clear for the people doing the audit. The only thing that is not very clear is am I allowed to make a folder below /opt/<appname>/ with full access so I can write there?

Writing outside /opt/<appname>/ is forbidden as I see in the guide I posted in the question...

Comment: You understood right. (It can be binary only, though) I just wanted to hint at the other possibility that gives you more control (the link you provided, item #5, box 'Advanced Users').

Comment: So do you mean that there is no problem with the review process if I try to make a folder and allow full access during the install of the package?

Comment: I don't speak on behalf of Canonical on the matter but I would expect that the review process is mostly automated and the zip file won't retain the file mode bits and cause trouble during review, which in turn could be defensively bypassed by providing a debian package, but I might be wrong. Please contact canonical directly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution and will write back if it worked.